# Gráfico para una web en React.js

Tags: reactjs, charts

Estoy haciendo un gráfico de barras y necesito cambiar los parámetros del eje y.

Necesito que los parámetros del eje Y sean Alto, Medio, Bajo, -, Bajo, Medio, Alto
[image: grafico1]

--

Llegando a obtener un resultado similar a este
[image: grafico2]

Dejaré el código que estoy usando para generar el gráfico:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Chart } from "react-google-charts";

const data = [
  ["Meses ", "datos1", "datos2"],
  ["Febrero", 200, -200],
  ["Marzo", 300, -200],
  ["Abril", 200, -200],
  ["Mayo", 300, -200],
  ["Junio", 100, -100],
];

const options = {
  legend: { position: "none" },
  backgroundColor: colors.light_gray2,
  isStacked: true,
  bar: { groupWidth: "90%" },
  chartArea: { width: "80%", height: "80%" },
  vAxis: {
    viewWindowMode: "explicit",
    viewWindow: {
      max: 300,
      min: -300,
    },
  },
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Chart chartType="ColumnChart" data={data} options={options} />
  );
}
```

Cualquier opción que conozcan me es válida.

Si necesitan más información estaré atento para disponerla.

Muchas gracias.